# LD_LIBRARY_PATH not show up

Tags: bash, environment-variables, aix

Yesterday I was working in setup some environment variables for the user `etladmin`. I did it in the `/home/etladmin/.profile` … and it was ok.

Today when I login, I can see all the variables, except for `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Only when I do `source .profile` is when I can see this variable.

In another user `.profile` I have the same variables and I can see the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` also… but when I run the `sudo –u etladmin bash` command `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` doesn't show up.

I will appreciate if you have any idea how to set this `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

This is what im doing in `.profile`:

```
export HOME_INFA_DIR=/etl/informatica/9.6.1
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$HOME_INFA_DIR
```

I'm using `bash` on AIX 7.1.

Answer (score 0):

The `.profile` file will not be sourced by a `bash` login shell *if* there is a `.bash_profile` or `.bash_login` file present. It will try these other files first.

Also, unless this file is sourced explicitly from `.bashrc`, a non-login interactive shell will not source it. You get one of these shells when you do `sudo -u user bash`.